# Convert & download the file node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

Hell everyone,

Please i need help to understand what i am doing wrong.

My problem is : i'am trying to create an app that convert from .xml to json then from json to .xlsx after that download the file as excel sheet.

anyway, the first part of the project was successfully done.
but when i try to convert the file json that i converted from .xml. to xlsx not working at all.

so the files are :

---

ControllerXML2Json.js

### working successfully and i can see the json data

```
const { json } = require('body-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const xml2js = require('xml2js')

let jsonString

async function xml2json() {
    try {
        const xml = fs.readFileSync('src/data/dataset.xml')
        const result = await xml2js.parseStringPromise(xml, { mergeAttrs: true })
        jsonString = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)
        //console.log(json)
        fs.writeFileSync('./public/data/result.json', jsonString)
        //return jsonString
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    convert(req, res) {
        let xmlFile = req.files.fileXML

        xmlFile.mv('src/data/dataset.xml', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err)
            } else {
                xml2json()
            }
        })

        res.redirect('/json')
    }
}
```

---

ControllerJson2Xlsx.js

not working at all

---

```
//const { json } = require("body-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const json2xlsx = require("json2xlsx");
const path = require("path");
//const fileName = "data.xlsx";

async function generateExcelFromJSON() {
  try {
    let data = JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync("public/data/result.json", {
        encoding: "utf8",
        flag: "r",
      })
    );
    
    let newWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    let newWB = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(newWS, newWB, "data");

    await xlsx.writeFile("./public/data/data.xlsx", newWB);
   // xlsx.writeFile(newWB, "./public/data/data.xlsx");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
module.exports = {
  download(req, res) {
    let jsonFile = req.files.fileJSON;

    jsonFile.mv("public/data/result.json", function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
        json2xlsx();
      }
    });
    res.redirect("/xlsx");
  },
};
```

---

route.js

---

```
const express = require('express')
const ControllerJson2Xlsx = require('./controllers/ControllerJson2Xlsx')
const ControllerXML2Json = require('./controllers/ControllerXML2Json')

const route = express.Router()

route.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'))

route.get('/json', (req, res) => res.render('json'))
route.post('/convert', ControllerXML2Json.convert);

route.get("/single", ControllerJson2Xlsx.download);
// route.post('/teste', (req, res) => {
//     return res.send(data)
// })

module.exports = route
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. If the problem is with the conversion from JSON to XSLX then you should show us the JSON, the code that tries to transform it, and a simple logging function to show how you are determining the result. There's no need to show us the code which converts your XML to JSON (which we can't see anyway so couldn't do the work to determine what the JSON looks like) or the Express code wrapping the whole thing.

Comment: [not working at all](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem. Is there an error? Is the wrong value returned? Is that wrong value `undefined`, `null`, or something else?

Comment: it gave's me nothing , no error no data no nothing , like the code not exist

Comment: Are you sure the code is executed at all?

Comment: the first part yes i am sure , but the second part no , i'm not sure. would you please help me to understand. thank you

Comment: Can you point out which line you are unsure whether it is being executed?

Comment: the all file ControllerJson2Xlsx.js , i am not sure that is working. the other file ControllerXML2Json  i'm sure that is working.

Comment: How do you test it?

Comment: i just execute the code and i can see the result with the front-end of the project.